# Setting example@outlook.com in outlook 2010?

Tags: email, outlook-2010, outlook.com

I am trying to setup my new **example@outlook.com** account in my outlook 2010.

I am try to reffer several links for manual server setting like 
http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/accountsettings.htm
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=21305

but I am unable to configure my email address. I am getting error while testing configuration in sending test mail.

help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of trial finally I manage to do it.. For this we don't have direct imap setting like outgoing server url , port etc.

This link we guide you to setup your example@outlook.com in outlook. Go through this...
http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/accountsettings.htm

Cheers :)